# Five points all lie on the conic

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

So I have a question that says...

> Find numbers $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ so that the five points $( 0,2 ),( -3 ,0 ),( 1, 5 ),( 1,1 ),( -1 ,1 )$ all lie on the conic $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ . Show, moreover, that $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ are uniquely determined up to a common factor.

I'm really confused as to how I would start this problem. I feel like I should be using matrix's at some point, but I need some equations with the points to start? Could some show/explain how I would get started going about this problem?

Comment: If you plug in the point $(0,2)$, you get the equation $(0)^2a+(0)(2)b+(2)^2c+(0)d+(2)e+f=0$

Comment: Just substitute the $(x,y)$ pairs into the equation and arbitrarily set $f=1$. You have five equations in five unknowns.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: It's safer not to set $f = 1$, since it's possible that the relevant conic might actually require $f = 0$.  Instead, you should solve five equations in $6$ unknowns; this will solve the problem in the form indicated, i.e. the solutions set $(a,\dots,f)$ will be determined up to a scalar.

Comment: I reviewed - f doesn't have to be 0. But he brings up a good point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$

we can solve the this system of linear equation:

$F(0,2)=F(-3,0)=F(1,5)=F(1,1)=F(-1,1)=0$
and get 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        d \\
        e \\
        f \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        (-7/6)f \\
        (19/6)f \\
        (-2/3)f \\
        (-19/6)f \\
        (5/6)f \\
        f \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
where $f$ can not be $0$

Answer (score 1):

Plugging each point into the given equation gives
\begin{align*}
4 \, c + 2 \, e + f &= 0 \\
9 \, a - 3 \, d + f &= 0 \\
a + 5 \, b + 25 \, c + d + 5 \, e + f &= 0 \\
a + b + c + d + e + f &= 0 \\
a - b + c - d + e + f &= 0 
\end{align*}
This system can be written in matrix form as $A\vec x=\vec 0$ where
\begin{align*}
A &=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
9 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 5 & 25 & 1 & 5 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right] &
\vec x &=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
e \\
f
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Now, row reduce $A$ to obtain
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{7}{6} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{19}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{19}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6}
\end{array}\right]
$$
This implies that our original system is equivalent to 
\begin{align*}
a + \frac{7}{6} \, f &= 0 &
b - \frac{19}{6} \, f&= 0 &
c + \frac{2}{3} \, f&= 0 &
d + \frac{19}{6} \, f&= 0 &
e - \frac{5}{6} \, f&= 0 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Solving the linear system, as others have shown, is perhaps the best way to go if you're doing this by hand and/or for the first time (and if you want to convince yourself of uniqueness-up-to-common-factor), but I'll just mention this ...

---

An equation of a conic through five points ---say, $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$--- is given by this determinant relation (where $P_x$ and $P_y$ are, respectively, the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of $P$):

> $$\left|\begin{matrix}
> x^2 & y^2 & x y & x & y & 1 \\
> A_x^2 & A_y^2 & A_x A_y & A_x & A_y & 1 \\
> B_x^2 & B_y^2 & B_x B_y & B_x & B_y & 1 \\
> C_x^2 & C_y^2 & C_x C_y & C_x & C_y & 1 \\
> D_x^2 & D_y^2 & D_x D_y & D_x & D_y & 1 \\
> E_x^2 & E_y^2 & E_x E_y & E_x & E_y & 1 \\
> \end{matrix}\right| = 0 \tag{$\star$}$$

So, in theory, one "simply" expands the determinant and reads-off the various coefficients. Of course, no one wants to expand a $6\times 6$ determinant by hand, but $(\star)$ comes in (*ahem*) handy if you have a computer algebra system available to do the symbol crunching.